# Finding basis for polynomials with coefficients summing to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathcal{P}_n[x]$ be the space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$ with real coefficients. I want to find a basis for the subspace of $\mathcal{P}_n[x]$ where the coefficents sum to zero, that is, a space $W$ such that
$$
W = \left\lbrace \sum^n a_k x^k  \Bigg| \sum^n  a_k = 0 \right\rbrace.
$$

Can one simply use a basis for $\mathcal{P}_n[x]$, for example $\lbrace 1, x, \dots, x^n \rbrace$? My reasoning is that if we have a $u \in W$, then we can write $u$ as a linear combination of elements from $\lbrace 1, x, \dots, x^n \rbrace$ by using the cofficients in $u$.

Comment: No. Because it gives lots of other polynomials which are not in $W$. Indeed none of $1,x,\dots$ are in $W$. You want things like $1-x$

Comment: @almagest yes but does the definition of a basis restrict the elements to *only* yield elements in the target space?

Comment: It does, since you require the basis vectors to span just the _subspace_. In your case, the vectors span the entire space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Notice that for $$p(x) := a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 \in \mathcal{P}_n[x]$$ the sum
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n a_k$$
is just $p(1)$, so $W$ is exactly the kernel of the (linear) map $$e_1 : \mathcal P_n[x] \to \Bbb R, \qquad p \mapsto p(1) .$$ Now, since $e_1$ evaluates any $p \in \mathcal P_n[x]$ at $x = 1$, it is convenient to rewrite $p(x)$ as a linear combination of powers of $$p(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n b_k (x - 1)^k .$$ What is $W$ in terms of the coefficients $b_k$?

Comment: Hi @TravisWillse , could you elaborate on what you mean by "a single (linear) constraint on an $(n+1)$-dimensional vector space? I have a similar doubt to the OP where i need to show that $U=\left\{a_{0}+a_{1} x+a_{2} x^{2} | a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2}=0\right\}$ is  a subspace of the vector space of all polynomial of degree 2 , and give a basis for it. But I don't understand your answer

Comment: Put another way, the map $\mathcal{P}_n[x] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $$a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 \mapsto a_0 + \cdots + a_n$$ is a linear map of rank $1$ (check this!), and by definition $W$ is its kernel. (NB we can also write this map as the evaluation map $p(x) \mapsto p(1)$.) Then, by the Rank-Nullity Theorem we have $$\dim W = \dim \mathcal{P}_n[x] - 1 = (n + 1) - 1 = n ,$$ so our basis of $W$ must have exactly $n$ elements. I wrote this answer a long time ago, and it perhaps isn't a great one, because it gives away the answer outright.

Comment: I've now rewritten the answer not to give away quite everything.